# How to set an item as selected in JList

Tags: java, jlist

I would like to create a `JButton` that when I press it it selects the last item of a `JList`.

itemsList is my `JList`, I already have some items on it

```
int selectedIndex = itemsList.getMaxSelectionIndex();
itemsList.setSelectedIndex(selectedIndex);
```

I tried this, but it doesn't select anything

Comment: `itemsList.setSelectedIndex(itemsList.getModel().getSize() - 1);`

Comment: that worked, Thank you!

Comment: You will want to go to the API for solutions to questions like these

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that this method: `getMaxSelectionIndex()` gets the max index of the **current selections** made in the JList (as per the JList API). This is not what it seems you want or need. Instead you need to get the size of the list, obtainable via the list's model, and remove 1 from it:

```
itemsList.setSelectedIndex(itemsList.getModel().getSize() - 1);
```